# MySQL Workbench used to allow me use shortcuts now it doesn't

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL workbench trying to query data from a sample database.  When I first started working with the database, it allowed me to use "shortcuts" when running my queries on tables within the my movie database.

For example INSERT INTO actor (first_name, last_name, current_date) VALUES ("Ryan", "Reynolds", "2023-07-21 9:35:21")

Now for some reason I have to specify both the database name and the table name.

For example INSERT INTO movie. Actor (first_name, last_name, current_date) VALUES ("Ryan", "Reynolds", "2023-07-21 9:35:21")

Is there a way to undo what ever I must have done to cause this to happen?

Comment: you can  add ```USE movie``` on top of the query to select which database to connect to